# Schwartz function with bounded Schwartz seminorms

Tags: complex-analysis, schwartz-space

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ is a Schwartz function such that there is $C>0$ such that all of its Schwartz seminorms are bounded by $C$:
$$
\sup_{m,n}\sup_x |x|^n |f^{(m)}(x)|\leq C.
$$
Must $f$ be 0?

My intuition is true, and I think it may be proved using complex analysis.

Comment: No complex analysis needed. For $\lvert x\rvert > 1$ fix $m = 0$ and let $n \to \infty$ to see that $f(x) = 0$. Thus such an $f$ has its support in $[-1,1]$. To finish it, write $$f^{(k)}(x) = \int_{-1}^x f^{(k+1)}(t)\,dt$$ for $k \geqslant 0$ and $x \in [-1,1]$ to conclude that for every $m$ you have $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant C \cdot \frac{2^m}{m!}$, hence $f(x) = 0$ also for $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1$.